# Errors in Testing SIM module

Tags: http, at-command

I am using SIM808 module and I want to Test HTTP Service of the module using AT commands. I started using AT command Tester to test the HTTP AT commands. But a constant Error i.e. `"Error Initializing HTTP Service"` is being returned when I use the `AT+HTTPINIT` AT-command.

It also sometimes returns an Error code: `CME 03, 'Operation Not Allowed'`. How can I prevent it from throwing this error? Also, can you tell me if there are any temporary URLs I can use with the module?